# Is it possible to replace a double number and write the program using only integers in C, with the same output?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, int

Is it possible to write a program like this, using only the integer type and the standard library `<stdio.h>` in C? The output of the remainder must be displayed as a decimal number with two numbers behind the comma.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 1;
int num3 = 6;
int num4 = 3;
int num5 = 7;
int num6 = 3;
int num7 = 9;
int num8 = 8;

int sum, product, Result;
double division;

int main()
{
    sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;
    product = num5 * num6 * num7;
    Result = ((++product) - (sum++)) * sum;

    int Integer_division = Result / (num8+ 1);
    int Remainder = Result % (num8+ 1);
    double division = Result / (num8+ 1);

    printf("Result = %d\n", Result);
    printf("Integer division = %d\n", Integer_division);
    printf("Remainder = %d\n", Remainder);
    printf("Division = %.02f\n", division);

    return 0;
}
```

I was thinking about splitting it into two halves and printing it with a comma in between(%d.%d)
but that sounds like my last resort...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The remainder of division is not the same as the fraction after the decimal point.

Comment: `.` is a period or decimal point, comma is `,`

Comment: If you're ok with expressing the result in fraction form: `printf("%d %d/%d\n", Integer_division, Remainder, num8+1)`

Comment: @bamar Some locales use a `','` as a "decimal point".

Comment: `((++product) - (sum++)) * sum;` is undefined behaviour. read and write `sum` separately without a sequence point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print floating-point like text from integers requires the sign, while-number part and the fraction part

```
char *sign = Result<0 ? "-":"";
int whole = abs(Integer_division);
char decimal_point = ',';  // behind the comma.
int hundredths = abs(Remainder *100/(num8+ 1));  // Convert fraction to
```

1/100ths

```
// now print it
printf("%s%d%c%02d", sign, whole, decimal_point, hundredths);
```

---

Yet this displays only a truncated result.  To *round* is work.

The usual way to mimic floating point output using integers it to consider the value as a fraction of 2 integer parts: `numerator`, `denominator` that needs scaling (e.g. x100 for .00 display) .  For simplicity, assume  `denominator > 0`.

First step is rounding due to finite display precision. Since the next step will involve an integer divide "truncate toward zero" and floating-point like display is usually "round to nearest", code needs to add a signed, unscaled 0.5 or one-half the denominator.

For simplicity, assume  `denominator > 0` and is odd so we can avoid half-way cases (even more work). Also assume no `int` overflow to avoid more work.

```
int numerator = Result;
int denominator = num8+ 1;
int scale = 100; // to print to 0.xx

int scaled_numerator = numerator * scale;
int scaled_half = denominator / 2;
if (scaled_numerator < 0) scaled_half = -scaled_half;
int rounded_scaled_numerator = scaled_numerator + scaled_half;
```

Now divide

```
int scaled_value = rounded_scaled_numerator/denominator;

char *sign = scaled_value<0 ? "-":"";
scaled_value = abs(scaled_value);
int whole = scaled_value / scale;
char decimal_point = ',';
int hundredths = scaled_value % scale;
printf("%s%d%c%02d", sign, whole, decimal_point, hundredths);
```

Comment: I do not require the full solution to the problem, only the answer to the question "Is it possible to do it only using int and <stdio.h>?" But good work right here...

Thank you.

Comment: @chumned there are no `char` here aside from `decimal_point`.  You could drop that and use `printf("%s%d,%02d", sign, whole, hundredths);`  .  There are  `char *` here: `sign, "-", "", "%s%d%c%02d"`.  If you can use `printf()`, your answer must be able to use a `char *`.